# Is the image of eggs at temples offensive?

Tags: temple, animals

I have recently read that a court in India has been asked to ban [Pokémon Go](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-asia-india-37294286) for these reasons:

> The high court in Gujarat state was asked to ban the game because its images of eggs in places of worship were "blasphemous" to Hindus and Jains.

I've read that eggs are not considered for consumption:

https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2602

> **Moral Reason**
>
> I have been taught that one reason such eggs are not considered suitable for *
>
> **Vedic Reason**
>
> ... overly stimulating ... not to be **consumed** as they lead to an unfit state of mind

However, the above question only addresses egg *consumption*; no eggs are consumed in the game.

Are images of eggs offensive?  Especially so at temples? If so why?

Comment: to be honest, the link that gave seems to have all the answers for your Question it seems

Comment: Status of Egg is somewhat unclear. Some Hindus consume **unfertilized egg** but traditional Hindus (especially Brahmins and Jains) consume only [**SATVIC FOOD**](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2660/3500). Definitely images of eggs are offensive especially at Vishnu or Jain Temples.

Comment: @AADHinduism which link, and in what way is it answer? It may be obvious to a hindu, but not myself...

Comment: @TheDestroyer I'm not understanding the link between consuming eggs, and images of them. Why are they offensive?

Comment: Is it due to the images implying the eggs are being ***offered*** at the temple?

Comment: Yes, it is offensive. Why would anyone want images of eggs at a place of worship? SHouldn't the imagery inspire spiritual reflection and not thoughts of games and good meant purely to sate the senses ? Also Eggs are not part of the worship ritual so why should they have a place? For information, eggs are considered the lowest form of food, while meat is acceptable even for those that are allowed to consume non-vegetarian food by religion.

Comment: @moonstar2001 "Why would anyone want images of eggs at a place of worship?" I'm trying to find out why anyone would mind? If you aren't playing the game it won't effect you.

Comment: @Pureferret. That is excessively simplistic. It is agreed that eggs do not have a place in a temple. Still placing images that do not belong is tantamount to bullying and deliberate disrespect. Expecting those that rever the temple ecosystem to ignore such blatant lack of respect is unfair and pseudo-secularism reserved exclusively for Hindus of India.

Comment: @moonstar2001 I apologise for beyond excessively simple about this sensitive subject,  I'm from a completely different culture/background so I'm not going to understand this in the same way you do. I just want to understand. Who has "agreed" this? Also please note that these images aren't "placed" they remain on a person's phone,  and don't even show the temple at the same time. Please help me understand the core issue.

Comment: @Pureferret Oh there's no need for apologies. If it is on an individual's  phone,and it is not displayed to others , it should be okay. I did not have this context before. It sounded like it was part of displayed art or something. As to who "agreed", there is a well-defined science for temple structures and functions. There are also well-defined rules for worship inside one's house and Hindus generally follow these sastra's. Did someone object to an individual playing pokemon go while at the temple?

Comment: @moonstar2001 I think a good answer would explain those well defined rules and sciences :D. Pokemon Go isn't even released in India yet.

Comment: @Pureferret Not required. People know and understand that there are rules and practitioners respect these rules. That is sufficient. A few may study these sciences and guide practitioners. Not everyone needs to study everything.

Comment: @moonstar2001 it's required by me to understand this though,  that's why I asked the question.

Comment: @Pureferret The specifics of the rules do not change the fact that rules exist.